# Looking for python equivalent of powershell code

Tags: python, powershell

I have some powershell code that I want to have an equivalent way to do with python:

```
$secretARgs = @{ fileName = "ssltls.crt"
>> fileAttachment = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("c:\users\myuser\git\myrepos\ssltls.crt")
>> } | ConvertTo-Json
```

It uses this to add to rest api call to store a file in an aplication called securevault.
I am not sure what the python method would be to do this ReadAllBytes and then convert to json.

Comment: You need to 1) read a file using [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and `f.read()`, 2) create a dict with these two keys, 3) convert it to JSON using [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.dump).

Comment: Do I need to open with rb so it it is ready binary? like: ``` in_file = open(file, "rb") 
                data = in_file.read() 
                dict = {}
                dict.update({"fileName":f"{file}"})
                dict.update({"fileAttachment":f"{data}"})
                dict2json = json.dumps(dict,indent=1) ```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, composition of `ReadAllBytes` and `ConvertTo-Json` should produce the int array. If that's the case, your code in the comments is quite close:

```
import json
import os.path

with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

output = {
    'fileName': os.path.basename(path),
    'fileAttachment': list(data)  # convert bytes to list
}

print(json.dumps(output, indent=1))
```

Comment: Why did you convert fileAttachment to a  list?

Comment: @archcutbank I checked what your powershell code produces, and it has file content as a list of ints. `bytes` returned from the file in binary mode are not json-serializable, but can be converted to the list. If you need a string instead, just open the file as in text mode and omit that conversion.